# Explode function ignores space character

Tags: php, explode

php:

```
$str="M. M. Grice and B. H. Alexander and L. Ukestad ";
// I need to explode the string by delimiter "and"
$output=explode("and",$str);
```

**Output:**
M. M. Grice
B. H. Alex
er
L. Ukestad

In the name "Alexander" there is a "and" so that too was splitted.
So, I changed it to `$output=explode(" and ",$str)// as delimiter "and" has space.` But it dint work.

where am I doing mistake? I tried `$output=explode("\ and\ ",$str)`.
But none of them worked

**Expected Output:**
M. M. Grice
B. H. Alexander
L. Ukestad

Comment: Works fine by exploding with `" and "`, see http://3v4l.org/dgbDH

Comment: `$output=explode(" and ",$str);` should work. what problem do you have using it?

Comment: Giving space both side works perfectly.

Comment: `"\ "` isn't a space character, `" "` is.... you don't need to try and escape spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided in the question:

```
$output=explode(" and ", $str);
```

**is** the correct way to get the desired output.

It does not work when the characters around the `and` in the input string `$str` are not regular spaces (`" " == chr(32)`) but tabs (`"\t" == chr(9)`), newlines (`"\n" == chr(10)`) or other white space characters.

The string can be split using `preg_split()`:

```
$output = preg_split('/\sand\s/', $str);
```

will use `and` surrounded by any whitespace character as a delimiter.

Another `regex` that can be used is:

```
$output = preg_split('/\band\b/', $str);
```

this will split `$str` using the word `and` as delimiter, no matter what characters (non-letter, non-digit, non-underscore) surround it. It will recognize `and` as a delimiter in the string provided in the question but also in `"M. M. Grice and B. H. Alexander (and L. Ukestad)"`.

An undesired side-effect is that the spaces around `and` are not part of the delimiter and they will remain in the split fragments. They can be easily removed by trimming the pieces returned by preg_split():

```
$str = "M. M. Grice and B. H. Alexander (and L. Ukestad)";
$output = array_map('trim', preg_split('/\band\b/', $str));
var_export($output);
```

will display:

```
array (
  0 => 'M. M. Grice',
  1 => 'B. H. Alexander (',
  2 => 'L. Ukestad)',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this better by regex:**  `preg_split("/\\sand\\s/i",$str);`  it explode in case (AND & and) both ..